# List files with nth letter m and starting with abc

Tags: linux

how can I list all the files from the current directory, whose names start with abc and have their 3rd and 4th letters either 'x' or 'y'?

Please help.

Comment: That list is empty, surely? if the name starts with `abc` then the 3rd letter cannot be `x` or `y`

Comment: Can you clarify - are you looking for all files that start with 'a' or 'b' or 'c' with a 3rd and 4th letter both either 'x' or 'y' ? Perhaps give examples of the filenames you expect to match and not match

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the question in the body. Please clarify what you want? (And perhaps try something yourself, it's probably rather simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is ill defined, however you can use bash/sh globs for `ls` like

```
ls abc[xy][xy]*
```

or if you need something more complex you can utilize the power of regexps. For example with (e)grep :

```
 ls  |  egrep "^abc(x|y){2}" | xargs -d\\n  ls -l
```

regexps are quite powerful, you probably will be able to do what you like.

Comment: ls abc[xy][xy]* worked. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the "3rd letter" part is a typo since you're also saying it should be "c".

```
ls -l abc[xy]*
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this guy correctly, then this is what he is looking for.

`find ./ -name "abc[m]*"`

or this way
`find ./ -name "ab[x][y]*"`

Comment: local directory is the default for find. (find -name ... is just fine)

Comment: @goteguru Possibly for find on Linux...

Comment: @goteguru Personally just used to the giving it a directory part. As i mostly look for files in other folders. barely in the same ones. Just something im used to :)

Comment: Yeah, it's for gnu. You *must* type the dir if you use osx or something archaic/rigidly standard compliant. I didn't say there is problem, it was just a hint if you are using gnu. :)